# Where to find Quickly Web Cam Widget?

Tags: application-development, quickly, widgets

According to [this page on developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/ubuntu-developer-stack/widgets/), (third paragraph second sentence), there is a Quickly Web Cam Widget, where do I find it? Tried googling but only found [Quickly Widgets](https://launchpad.net/quidgets/+series).

Comment: What I understand from that line is that Cam Widget is part of the Quickly Widgets package, so if you can extract and explore the Quickly Widgets then you should find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from quickly.widgets import web_cam_box
```

Here's the contents of quickly.widgets:

```
Help on package quickly.widgets in quickly:

NAME
    quickly.widgets

FILE
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickly/widgets/__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    conventions
    dictionary_grid
    grid_column
    grid_filter
    media_player_box
    press_and_hold_button
    tests (package)
    text_editor
    url_fetch_progressbox
    web_cam_box
```

and the beginning of the web_cam_box help:

```
NAME
    quickly.widgets.web_cam_box

FILE
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickly/widgets/web_cam_box.py

DESCRIPTION
    A VBox that tries to turn on and display the default webcam for the
    computer on which it is running. It is also capable of saving an image
    from the webcam to the user's Picture directory.
```

There's more info on functions and usage in the help.